# Accessing a non-Silverlight assembly in Silverlight using COM

Tags: .net, com

I’m trying to access a non SL assembly  in my SL application. I have wrap the non SL assembly in COM wrapper using “Register for COM introp”. 
Internally this assembly loaded another assembly using reflection and calls its method using Method.Invoke.

Application is getting crash when I call this COM component. It looks like it is able to load the assembly through reflection but it is unable to make the call to  methods using reflection (Mehtod.Invoke).

I can only see the following log in Event viewer

*Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 8.0.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce79912
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec49b8f
Exception code: 0x4000001f
Fault offset: 0x000ce695
Faulting process id: 0x2f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce47e8417f56c3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 86ef1dd9-b3db-11e2-8faa-b499baf11a4f*

Comment: Are you sure you can execute local COM components using Silverlight? That would be a security nightmare. I don't think it's possible at all. Maybe you should start small... can you call a COM component that's just returning "hello world"?

Comment: Yes. I can run the sample program and able to call it. Using AutomationFactory.CreateObject() I can create a COM object and able to call its function.

Comment: Did you set `OOB` and `elevated trust` in your new non-sample project as well? If so, you will need to debug your dll. Does it work without all the COM stuff, just as a normal .NET assembly called from ConsoleApplication1?

Comment: Yes. I had set the OOB and elevated trust on project. It is working fine without COM stuff form Console App. Even with Silverlight I can see it is loading the DLL using reflection, getting all types etc. but its not able to call the method using Method.Invoke().